# problem with migrating many to many ploymorphic relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relation

i have **Category** model, and i want to use it for *posts* and *topics*.
and i think should use many to many ploymorphic relation, but in migrating i get this error:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'forum.categoriables' doesn't ex
ist (SQL: alter table `categoriables` add `category_id` int unsigned not null, add `categoriable_id` int unsigned not null, add `ca
tegoriable_type` varchar(191) not null)
```

this is **categories** table:

```
 Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();

            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('parent_id');
            $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and this is categoriables table:

```
Schema::table('categoriables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('categoriable_id');
            $table->string('categoriable_type');
        });
```

each of them are in separate migration file.

Comment: Migrations go in order of the date stamp prepended to the file name, so make sure 'categoriables' is first, then maybe 'categoriables' should be Schema::create instead of Schema::table?

Comment: No worries.  Now that I re-read it, maybe 'categoriables' should be second actually, but that would only matter if you used the fk relations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is what you want, but currently you are "ALTERING" the categoriable. Maybe try changing to Schema::create ?

```
Schema::create('categoriables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoriable_id');
        $table->string('categoriable_type');
    });
```